# Extract only HTML tags and attributes from a html string using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to fetch only the HTML content along with the attributes and remove the text.

Input String:

```
String html = "<p>An <br/><b></b> <a href='http://example.com/' target=\"h\"> <b> example <a><p></b>this is  the </a> link </p>";
```

**Output**

```
<p><br></br><b></b><a href="http://example.com/" target="h"><b><a><p></p></a></b></a></p>
```

**Edit:**
Most of the questions in google or stackoverflow are only related to removing the html and extract text only. I spent around 3 hours to come across the below mentioned solutions. So posting it here as it will help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps someone like me looking to remove only the text content from the HTML string.

**Output**

```
<p><br></br><b></b><a href="http://example.com/" target="h"><b><a><p></p></a></b></a></p>
```

```
String html = "<p>An <br/><b></b> <a href='http://example.com/' target=\"h\"> <b> example <a><p></b>this is  the </a> link </p>";
       Traverser traverser = new Traverser();

       Document document = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());// you can use the html parser as well. which will add the html tags

       document.traverse(traverser);
       System.out.println(traverser.extractHtmlBuilder.toString());
```

By appending the node.attributes will includes all the attributes.

```
    public static class Traverser implements NodeVisitor {

        StringBuilder extractHtmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        @Override
        public void head(Node node, int depth) {
            if (node instanceof Element && !(node instanceof Document)) {
                extractHtmlBuilder.append("<").append(node.nodeName()).append(node.attributes()).append(">");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
            if (node instanceof Element && !(node instanceof Document)) {
                extractHtmlBuilder.append("</").append(node.nodeName()).append(">");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Another Solution:**

```
 Document document = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
        for (Element element : document.select("*")) {
            if (!element.ownText().isEmpty()) {
                for (TextNode node : element.textNodes())
                    node.remove();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(document.toString());
```